# How can I get the floating treasure ball on Atlas' hand?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

In Bresha Ruins 005AF, I can ride a chocobo to the railing near the entry gate and bounce along the fingers of Atlas' hand.  But there is a bouncing treasure ball on one of the fingers that I can't seem to reach, no matter which direction I jump from.

How can I get to that irksome sphere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to revisit the area after you get to a certain point in `Episode 3 Part 2` (Sunleth Waterscape) where you will be given the `Moogle Throw` ability, this part will also teach you how to use it.

There is plenty of other treasure that can be obtained the same manner, but you will need to progress the game to at least this point first.

Comment: Cheers!  Seems weird given the chocobo leap point nearby.  I'll just have to wait it out then.

Answer (score 5):

This will be available later on with the moogle throw ability.